# How to customize Material stepper component showing label at the top?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material Stepper. I found Stepper label position left, bottom, I want to show two stepper label position top of the stepper and bottom of stepper circle icon shown in center.

[Stepper label position should Top and Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJkdx.png)

Comment: I couldn't understand what you want. can you add a picture of the result you want?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJkdx.png

Answer (score 0):

Your `Step` element structure should be like this:

```
<Step
  key={label}
  completed={completed[index]}
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
  }}
>
  <Typography>The top text</Typography>
  <StepLabel sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
    the bottom text
  </StepLabel>
</Step>
```